# Printing in ROOT with Info() function

Tags: printing, root-framework, info

I'm trying to make some print statements in ROOT using Info, as in
Info("execute()","the pt of the jet = %.2f Gev", (*jets_itr)->pt());
and I am trying to find some documentation that will tell me what symbols to use to use for ints, doubles, etc (I think know from another source that .2f is a float, but otherwise I'm just guessing). 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the full list here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/